# Which Versions of FireFox Should I Support?

Tags: firefox, cross-browser, firefox-3, firefox2, browser-support

I have recently built a template for a website that I see looks *slightly* different in different versions of FireFox. I was wondering, as a rule of thumb, which versions of FireFox are worth supporting? FF2 and up? FF3 and up?

Thanks for your help,
spryno724

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on your audience, really.  Have you looked at your logs/analytics data to see what the majority of users are hitting your pages with?  You will need that piece of data to answer your own question well.

Having said that: with FF4 out now, I think it is safe to support 3.6 and above only.

The Mozilla community tends to take the upgrade path quicker than most.

Comment: Yeah, they are pretty good about that. Thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your audience, but generally people keep non-IE browsers up to date.

So most people will be on at least Firefox 3.5. Very few will be using 2.

Comment: I see, thank you. That being said I will forget about the small details that don't look perfect on a FireFox 2 browser!

Answer (score 1):

Here are Firefox version usage stats:

http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_firefox.asp

Comment: Those stats are skewed against *web professionals* (apparently the only ones yet to discover http://w3fools.com).

Comment: I appreciate that, but those are only stats for those who visited that site, not globally. Also it is _probably_ a lot of web developers who visit that site, and most likely, keep their browser pretty much up to date. I'm looking more for the general population, who may not be as diligent.

Comment: This was given as a general idea of how to approach the problem: look at the browser stats.

Comment: I see... It is a good _general_ idea. The only thing is these stats are from a knowledgeable, developer majority, not the general public.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would only support 3 and up. I have very little tolerance for those still on old systems and would only provide full browser support for things like a banking website that EVERYONE needs access to. Otherwise, I would try to wean users off older browsers.

Comment: Gotcha. Weaning users off old browsers sound like a good idea!